# Count Based on the Condition of Each Row and Return the result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count the data based on the condition of each row, like what the `COUNTIFS()` function does in Excel.

For example:

```
UserID     Row_Num   Date_    
1          1         0621     
1          2         0622      
1          3         0623
1          4         0625 
1          5         0626 
1          6         0628  
1          7         0630 
2          1         0621 
2          2         0622 
2          3         0623
2          4         0625 
2          5         0626 
2          6         0628  
2          7         0630
```

This is how my row data looks like. And these are the logic I used to calculate the data:

- If the UserID is the same
- If Date_ is in past 5 days

If using Excel, my function criteria would be:

```
COUNTIFS(A:A, UserID, C:C, "<="&Date, C:C, ">="&Date-5)
```

So the result should look like this:

```
UserID     Row_Num   Date_    Count_   
1          1         0630    3
1          2         0628    3
1          3         0626    4
1          4         0625    4
1          5         0623    3
1          6         0622    2
1          7         0621    1
2          1         0630    3
2          2         0628    3
2          3         0626    4
2          4         0625    4
2          5         0623    3
2          6         0622    2
2          7         0621    1
```

Comment: Don't think of table as a worksheet, it *isn't* a worksheet. Tables and Worksheets are, in truth, nothing a like. Once you start to understand this, and start to use set based thinking, you'll find working out solutions is likely easier.

Comment: Is your `Date_` column actually a `date` or a `varchar(4)`? If the latter, you're going to have problems, especially around 31 December/01 January.

Comment: some `case` `when` may be of help.

Comment: since not everyone is versed in excel, maybe you could explain your logic with words too. does it goes back x number of rows or x number of days

Comment: @ThomA Thanks for the suggestion! I'm still a beginner and I would learn to think of tables to be a different thing from worksheet. 
And my `date` data is actually varchar(4), but don't worried about it because there's no cross-year data.

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks for the suggestion! I've edited the post to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually solved by doing a triangular join in a correlated subquery, where you fetch back some data for each row:

```sql
-- Table for test data
CREATE TABLE #data (userid int, row_num int, date_ datetime, count_ int)

-- Populate with data
INSERT INTO #data
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1,1,'20230630',3)
    ,   (1,2,'20230628',3)
    ,   (1,3,'20230626',4)
    ,   (1,4,'20230625',4)
    ,   (1,5,'20230623',3)
    ,   (1,6,'20230622',2)
    ,   (1,7,'20230621',1)
    ,   (2,1,'20230630',3)
    ,   (2,2,'20230628',3)
    ,   (2,3,'20230626',4)
    ,   (2,4,'20230625',4)
    ,   (2,5,'20230623',3)
    ,   (2,6,'20230622',2)
    ,   (2,7,'20230621',1)
) t ([UserID], [Row_Num], [Date_], [Count_])

-- Actual fetch
SELECT  *
,   (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    #data d2 -- Get previous rows for some user
        WHERE   d2.userid = d.userId
        AND d2.date_ <= d.date_
        AND d2.date_ >= dateadd(day, -4, d.date_)
        AND d2.row_num BETWEEN d.row_num AND d.row_num + 5 -- performance optimization
    ) as actual_count
FROM    #data d
```

I create a correlated subquery which counts rows for same user and dates between current date and 4 days back. Just as a performance optimization i make sure it doesn't fetch more than 5 row_nums back.

Note that sql server doesn't work with "part"-dates, and needs full year-month-date string.

The performance of such tasks is usually not super unless you have good index on UserID and row_num.

As an alternative one can do a number of LAG calls (4 for each date and count that way), but not sure the performance would be better

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation! This is really clear that I can fully understand it. I would try this method and think of how to make my table more easy to use.